# SQL Server int conversion ignores subquery?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in my database. One has shipment data with zip code location and the other table has a complete zip code listing of all zips in the US. I just included the relevant columns below to keep it simple.

Table: ZipCodes

- ZipCode PK  char(5)

Table: Shipments

- ShipToZip varchar(10)
- AMT decimal(10,2)

So some of the shipment data may be to non-US addresses, and others may include the +4 for US zip codes (XXXXX-XXXX) which is why the shipment table has up to 10. All I need to do is export the query as a CSV, however I need the zip codes converted to integer.

```
SELECT CAST(ShipToZIP AS INT) AS [target],SUM(cast(AMT as int)) AS [total]
FROM
    (SELECT LEFT(ShiptoZip,5) ShipToZip,Amt
        FROM Shipments
        WHERE LEFT(SHIPTOZIP,5) IN (SELECT zipcode from ZipCodeLocations)
    ) Q
GROUP BY CAST(ShipToZIP AS INT)
```

When I run that query however, I keep getting conversion errors for the Canadian zip codes. If I run the inner Q query by itself, every single record is a valid US only code.

How can I force the subquery to run first? I tried making it a CTE per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797411/how-can-i-force-sql-server-to-execute-subquery-first-and-filter-the-where-stat) however it didn't work either.

Comment: Treating zip codes as integers is a problem not just for Canadian codes but also US zip codes that have a leading 0. You need to take a really hard look at that requirement because it's so problematic.  E.g. spe u all case for converting leading-zero zip codes from int to 5 char string... Why treat a zip code as an int? You can't do math with it.

Comment: Well I needed it work with some data between files and Excel, annoyingly, always removes the leading 0 no matter what I do when I save as CSV. So I was trying to save an extra step by just outputting it as integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the execution plan, and I'm not sure you can force the subquery to run 1st.

You could do this and prevent having to CAST to an INT.

```
SELECT CASE ShiptoZip WHEN LEFT(ShiptoZip) = '0' THEN RIGHT(ShiptoZip, LEN(ShiptoZip) - 1) ELSE ShiptoZip END AS [target],
SUM(cast(AMT as int)) AS [total]
FROM
  (SELECT LEFT(ShiptoZip,5) ShipToZip,Amt
    FROM Shipments
    WHERE LEFT(SHIPTOZIP,5) IN (SELECT zipcode from ZipCodeLocations)
  ) Q
GROUP BY CASE ShiptoZip WHEN LEFT(ShiptoZip) = '0' THEN RIGHT(ShiptoZip, LEN(ShiptoZip) - 1) ELSE ShiptoZip END
```

Your other alternative is to CAST to an INT after your aggregation if you must go that route.

```
SELECT CAST(ShipToZIP AS INT) AS [target],[total]
FROM
(SELECT LEFT(ShiptoZip,5) ShipToZip, SUM(cast(AMT as int)) AS [total]
    FROM Shipments
    WHERE LEFT(SHIPTOZIP,5) IN (SELECT zipcode from ZipCodeLocations)
    GROUP BY ShipToZIP
) Q
```